# Definition of Alternating $(k,0)$- and $(k,l)$-tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, mathematics, linear-algebra

I know that one can define the alternating subspace of $(0,l)$-tensors in a straightforward way. These are the renowned $l$-forms. However, I have been searching in the literature for a definition of the space of the alternating $(k,0)$- and $(k,l)$-tensors and have found nothing. Can they be defined?

PS. I know that the question is mathematical but there are strong connections between tensor calculus and physics. That's why I am asking the question in Physics SE.

Comment: They can be defined in exactly the same way, but they are not as useful because you don't have an equivalent of the exterior derivative.

Comment: Also, alternating $(k,l)$ tensors don't make sense, as you cannot exchange two arguments if one if from the "k" part and the other's from the "l" part. Unless you have some preferred isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent spaces, like a metric. Since then you turn the (k,l) tensor into a (k+l,0) or (0,k+l) tensor .

Comment: @Uldreth Hmm I see. However, couldn't one define a $(k,l)$-tensor that is alternating in the $k$ indices and in the $l$ indices independently?

Comment: @GK Sure, you can.